# Change table cell position using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change table cell position using jQuery. String could vary.

## Before

```
A | string
B | string
C | string
string | A
string | B
string | C
string | A
string | B
string | C
```

## After - I want it change this way.

```
A | string
string | A
string | A
B | string
string | B
string | B
C | string
string | C
string | C
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A | string</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B | string</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C | string</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I made it with sources below, but it's not practical because other cells like 'D', 'E', etc. can be added in the future.

```
$("tr:contains(' | A')").insertAfter("tr:contains('A | ')");
$("tr:contains(' | B')").insertAfter("tr:contains('B | ')");
$("tr:contains(' | C')").insertAfter("tr:contains('C | ')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it dynamicly like this

```js
$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
   var text = $(this).find('td').first().text(); 
   var match = (text.match(/^[A-Z] \|/))
   if(match){
      $("tr:contains(' | " + match[0][0] + "')").insertAfter("tr:contains('" + match[0]  + " ')");
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A | string</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B | string</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C | string</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>string | C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it and worked perfectly!

The problem is the part 'A, B, C' is actually japanese strings and 
I don't know how to apply to my real code...
I mean they are strings like 'green apple', 'banana' and 'peach' but in Japanese.
I just changed them to ask in English, so sorry...

I would really appriciate you if you could help me again.

Comment: I think I will make another question. Thank you so much!